# returning in the middle of a using block

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable, using-statement

Something like:

```
using (IDisposable disposable = GetSomeDisposable())
{
    //.....
    //......
    return Stg();
}
```

I believe it is not a proper place for a return statement, is it?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

As several others have pointed out in general this is not a problem.

The only case it will cause you issues is if you return in the middle of a using statement and additionally return the in using variable.  But then again, this would also cause you issues even if you didn't return and simply kept a reference to a variable.

```
using ( var x = new Something() ) { 
  // not a good idea
  return x;
}
```

Just as bad

```
Something y;
using ( var x = new Something() ) {
  y = x;
}
```

Comment: Just I was about to edit my question about the point you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Please help me understand why this is bad. I would like to return a Stream that I am using in a helper function to another function for image processing. It seems like the Stream will be disposed if I do this?

Comment: @JohnShedletsky In this case your function call should be wrapped with using. Like using(Stream x = FuncToReturnStream()){...} and no using inside FuncToReturnStream.

Comment: @JohnShedletsky I'm sure it's because `return` statement makes the end of the `using` block inaccessible by any code paths. The end of the `using` block needs to be ran so the object can be disposed if needed.

Answer (score 171):

It's perfectly fine.

You are apparently thinking that

```
using (IDisposable disposable = GetSomeDisposable())
{
    //.....
    //......
    return Stg();
}
```

is blindly translated into:

```
IDisposable disposable = GetSomeDisposable()
//.....
//......
return Stg();
disposable.Dispose();
```

Which, admittedly, would be a problem, and would make the `using` statement rather pointless --- which is why that's **not** what it does.

The compiler makes sure that the object is disposed before control leaves the block -- regardless of how it leaves the block.

Comment: Great answer @James Curran! But it makes me rather curious what it IS translated into. Or is that only expressible in IL ? (which I have never really tried reading before).

Comment: @Bart - I think of it as evaluating the return expression into a temporary variable, then doing the dispose, then returning the temporary variable.

Comment: @James Curran. From top to here, Only you explained  what happed in the background. Many thanks.

Comment: @Bart it's probably translated to: try { ...your code... } finally { x.Dispose(); }

Comment: Related, a nice workaround I found for working with `IDisposable`s that I need to "use" after the function returns is to pass in a `Func`. For example, I have some helpers that create connections and execute queries, but I can pass in a `Func<IDataReader, T>` to extract the result. My code only needs one set of `using` blocks and my other functions focus on setting up the queries and parameters.

Answer (score 106):

It's absolutely fine - no problem at all. Why do you believe it's wrong?

A using statement is just syntactic sugar for a try/finally block, and as Grzenio says it's fine to return from a try block too.

The return expression will be evaluated, then the finally block will be executed, then the method will return.

Comment: James Curran's answer explains what I was thinking.

Answer (score 30):

This will work perfectly fine, just as returning in the middle of `try{}finally{}`

Answer (score 20):

That is totally acceptable. A *using* statement ensures the IDisposable object will be disposed no matter what.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.

Answer (score 19):

The code bellow shows how `using` is working:

```
private class TestClass : IDisposable
{
   private readonly string id;

   public TestClass(string id)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is created.", id);
      this.id = id;
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is disposed.", id);
   }

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return id;
   }
}

private static TestClass TestUsingClose()
{
   using (var t1 = new TestClass("t1"))
   {
      using (var t2 = new TestClass("t2"))
      {
         using (var t3 = new TestClass("t3"))
         {
            return new TestClass(String.Format("Created from {0}, {1}, {2}", t1, t2, t3));
         }
      }
   }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
   Assert.AreEqual("Created from t1, t2, t3", TestUsingClose().ToString());
}
```

Output:

> 't1' is created.
>   't2' is created.
>   't3' is created.
>   'Created from t1, t2, t3' is created.
>   't3' is disposed.
>   't2' is disposed.
>   't1' is disposed.

The disposed are called after the return statement but before the exit of the function.

Comment: Please note that some C# objects dispose in a custom fashion, for example, WCF clients is a using statement like above return "can't access disposed object"

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps it isn't 100% true that this is acceptable...

If you happen to be nesting usings and returning from within a nested one, it might not be safe.

Take this as an example:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var textwriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(textwriter))
        {
            //..write some stuff to the stream using the CsvWriter
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I was passing in a DataTable to be outputted as csv. With the return in the middle, it was writing all the rows to the stream, but the outputted csv was always missing a row (or multiple, depending on the size of the buffer). This told me that something wasn't being closed properly.

The correct way is to make sure all the previous usings are disposed properly:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var textwriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(textwriter))
        {
            //..write some stuff to the stream using the CsvWriter
        }
    }

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```