# Does a MemoryStream get disposed of automatically when returning it as an ActionResult?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, using, memorystream

```
public ActionResult CustomChart(int reportID)
{
    Chart chart = new Chart();

    // Save the chart to a MemoryStream
    var imgStream = new MemoryStream();
    chart.SaveImage(imgStream);
    imgStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Return the contents of the Stream to the client
    return File(imgStream, "image/png");
}
```

I am accustomed to using the 'using' statement in conjuction with MemoryStreams. Is this a scenario where the 'using' statement is not necessary? Or is it valid to call return inside of a 'using' statement?

EDIT:

For my purposes I have found that the introduction of a 'using' statement does NOT work (throws an ObjectDisposedException). Here's what I'm doing with it client-side:

```
$('#ReportTest').bind('load', function () {
                        $('#LoadingPanel').hide();
                        $(this).unbind('load');
                    }).bind('error', function () {
                        $('#LoadingPanel').hide();
                        $(this).unbind('error');
                    }).attr('src', '../../Chart/CustomChart?ReportID=' + settings.id);
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to use the 'using' statement when dealing with classes that implement IDisposable, whether or not you believe ASP.NET is going to clean up after you.

Comment: what does `File(stream, string)` do with the stream? typically the object which created the stream should also dispose of the stream. in that case you would be responsible disposing of the stream.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker would the `Dispose()` method even be called?  I would think after `return` is called it wouldn't complete the `using` block.

Comment: Possible dupe'ish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662773/returning-in-the-middle-of-a-using-block

Comment: @Shark The dispose is called in a `finally`, so yes - it'll get called.

Comment: Create a Stream descendant that writes out messages using Debug.WriteLine to verify what happens.

Comment: It is good practice to `Dispose` disposable objects. But for `MemoryStream` the only thin that will do is prevent you from reading/writing to it. So you current implementation works fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Does a MemoryStream get disposed of automatically when returning it as an ActionResult?

Yes, MVC (at least version 3) will clean it up for you. You can take a [look at the source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FileStreamResult.cs) of the `WriteFile` method in `FileStreamResult`:

```
protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response) {
    // grab chunks of data and write to the output stream
    Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
    using (FileStream) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];

        while (true) {
            int bytesRead = FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
            if (bytesRead == 0) {
                // no more data
                break;
            }

            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

The line `using (FileStream) {` will place the Stream in a using block, thus Disposing of it when it has written the contents to the Http Response.

You can also verify this behavior by creating a dummy stream that does this:

```
public class DummyStream : MemoryStream
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Do I get disposed?");
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

So MVC *will* dispose it.

Comment: Thank you for the definitive answer. :)

Comment: ...intriguingly enough, if I use a 'using' statement for my applications -- I generate an internal server error.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Are you able to obtain a stack trace & exception? Depending on the Stream; it may not like getting disposed twice.

Comment: When render gets called for the page I am told that the stream is invalid. It just doesn't like getting GC'ed that early.

Comment: A few years late... but I moved the accepted answer over. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 2):

Sean: Do NOT use 'using' as it will Dispose the object. Leaving MVC accessing a Disposed object. Hence the exception(server error) you experienced is certainly an ObjectDisposedException. The WriteFile function previously posted Disposes the object for you.

Answer (score 2):

A MemoryStream is not necessary in this situation. You can avoid it by creating a Custom ActionResult like this :

```
public class ChartResult : ActionResult
{
    private Chart _chart;

    public ChartResult(Chart chart)
    {
        if (chart == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("chart");
        _chart = chart;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "image/png";
        response.BufferOutput = false;

        _chart.ImageType = ChartImageType.Png;
        _chart.SaveImage(response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually pretty nice solution!  Seems like it'd save 1 buffer copy too.  (May depend on how big a deal it is to keep `Chart` alive that long though)

Answer (score -3):

The following is valid code that disposes of the stream. If enclosed in a `using` block the `MemoryStream.Dispose()` method will be called automatically when returning.

```
public ActionResult CustomChart(int reportID)
{
    Chart chart = new Chart();

    using (var imgStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        chart.SaveImage(imgStream);
        imgStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return File(imgStream, "image/png");
    }
}
```

You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a `try` block and then calling `Dispose` in a finally block. In fact, according to the MSDN documentation this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler. And in a `try..finally` block the `finally` will always be executed even when `try` exits through `return`.

The compiler will translate the `using` block to the following:

```
MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream();

try 
{
    chart.SaveImage(imgStream);
    imgStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return File(imgStream, "image/png");
}
finally
{
    if (imgStream != null) 
        ((IDisposable)imgStream).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Won't that yank the stream out from underneath the File object?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That is what I am wondering, too. And if it doesn't... why does it not? :)

Comment: +1 for comment @SeanAnderson I'd like to see the documentation on this myself.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, it will.

Comment: If the stream is processed directly in the `File` constructor there should not be a problem.

Comment: File is not a constructor here, it is a method on the controller.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen right, still depends on what that method actually does.

Comment: So have we established that this works or not? If it doesn't, I'm going to close this question as too localized.

Comment: I just tried it out in my application. The introduction of a using statement does NOT work for my application. I have an internal server error when trying to render the image file.

Comment: I do not recommend doing this: it will close the stream before returning it and you will get an error. Suppose you are returning a stream with a pdf to be displayed on a dialog, you will get "cannot access closed stream error" if you put the return inside a using clause\

Comment: Just throwing my $.02 in that this is how I had it implemented thinking it should be this way and it totally doesn't work.  It does indeed yank the stream out from File(..) before it has a chance to use it.  I googled "will file dispose the stream? mvc" to verify (to verify what I suspected after a bit more testing) and this is what I was led to.