# XMLSerializer not working. No exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml-serialization

I am using below code to serialize a class.

```
    public static string SerializeToString<T>(this T toSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }

    }
```

This code is working intermittently. Sometimes it return the serialized string and sometimes not. There is no exception anywhere.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You need to [Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) the `StringWriter` before calling `ToString()`:

```
public static string SerializeToString<T>(this T toSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
        textWriter.Flush();
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }

}
```

When data is written to a `StringWriter` it is written to an internal buffer first. Data in the internal buffer is not recognized when calling `ToString()`.

Alternatively you can use the following code:

```
    public static string SerializeToString<T>(this T toSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Here the `StringWriter` writes its data to the `StringBuilder`. By using the `using` keyword the `StringWriter` gets closed automatically when leaving the block what forces the `StringWriter` to flush its data to the given `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What difference will it make?

Comment: Have a look [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340106/what-is-the-purpose-of-flush-in-java-streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340106/what-is-the-purpose-of-flush-in-java-streams) for more information about flushing streams (even if it's Java related).

Comment: ok but my perception was if we are using "using" code block we dont need it. Using itself will handle flushing and disposing it.

Comment: This is correct, but `textWriter.ToString()` is evaluated **before** the `StringWriter` is closed (and flushed) by leaving the `using` block. Have a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662773/returning-in-the-middle-of-a-using-block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662773/returning-in-the-middle-of-a-using-block).

Comment: ok I am using the first block of code for now. Will check if issue comes again. Thanks for your answer