# Angular 2 with c# backend Http get with variables doesnt work

Tags: c#, angular, http

I've been making a project generated many things from out of the database with HTTP request. This has 3 larger queries into 1 C# class

```
    public IEnumerable<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Pagina> Paginas { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Opmaak> Opmaak { get; set; }
    public string Errors { get; set; }
```

This works like a charm, Main Object

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7tNj.jpg - HTTP Network Summary

```
    public Main Get()
    {
        return Main.getAll();
    }
```

This can't return anthing, Same Main Object

https://i.stack.imgur.com/koOfu.jpg - HTTP Network Summary

```
    public Main Get(string username, string password)
    {
        Login value = new Login(username: username, password: password);
        return Main.getAll(value);
    }
```

Question, How do I properly send variables over a HTTP request

---

Webconfig C#

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);
        AddRoutes(config);

    }

    private static void AddRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{username}/{password}",
            defaults: new { username = RouteParameter.Optional, password = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
    }

    private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
            origins: "http://lvh.me:4200",
            headers: "*",
            methods: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
```

C# Main.cs

```
 public static Main getAll()
 {
    using (CheckPlusEntities db = new CheckPlusEntities())
    {
        Main Totaal = new Main();

        //Filling Totaal 

        return Totaal;
    }
}

 public static Main getAll(Login Login)
 {
     using (CheckPlusEntities db = new CheckPlusEntities())
     {
         Main Totaal = new Main();

        //Filling Totaal 

        return Totaal;
     }
 }
```

Angular 2 Service

Wrong =

```
    get = {


            event: (username:string, password:string): Promise<any> => {    


            let url = "http://{URL}:8080/CheckPlusApi/api/Main/Get/" + username + "/" + password;
            return this._http.get(url)
                .map(response => {
                    return response.json(); // Has a value
                },
                   error =>  {
                       this.errorMessage = <any>error
                }).toPromise();
            }
        }
```

Good =

```
    getTest = {
            event: (): Promise<any> => {            
                return this._http.get('http://{URL}:8080/CheckPlusApi/api/Main/Get')
                .map(response => {
                    return response.json(); 
                },
                   error =>  {
                       this.errorMessage = <any>error
                }).toPromise();
            }     
    };
```

Comment: Is your problem the error that is returned in the image you posted? It says your `DbContext` has been disposed but you're trying to use it anyway...

Comment: @silkfire 

Hello, thanks for the reaction. Both functions open with a using(db)


            using (CheckPlusEntities db = new CheckPlusEntities())
            {
                Main Totaal = new Main();

Comment: Can you mention the client side Java Script code snippet? Actual error could be how you are passing the data.

Comment: @SachinGaur Added to the post

Comment: @Kapein Check in your stack trace where exactly the error occurs. Also, your methods says they should return an object of type  `Main` but you never return anything.

Comment: @silkfire I didn't properly edit it, it does return with the correct variables into the MainController

Comment: Thanks @silkfire I wasn't allowed to use a Using(db){}, I wouldn't have found that out.

Comment: @Kapein Yeah I figured that. Did that solve your question?

Comment: @silkfire it does, however can you explain why the one get works and the other doesn't?

Comment: @Kapein At the moment, both methods are identical. Is that correct?

Comment: @silkfire the only difference is that one takes username and password as arguments.

Comment: Could it be something in your `Login` constructor?

Comment: Flat text / Post body wouldn't even work

Comment: @silkfire Thank you for your help, I'll waddle ahead now, was stuck for over 10 hours

Comment: Np. Do you want me to post an answer that you can accept?

Comment: If you would like it sure, I did however add one myself already feel free to take it over

Comment: refer to this, I believe this is more about the scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662773/returning-in-the-middle-of-a-using-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your `using` clause.

Try removing it by changing:

```
using (CheckPlusEntities db = new CheckPlusEntities())
```

to this:

```
CheckPlusEntities db = new CheckPlusEntities();
```